# Nuxt.js how can I use external static server?

Tags: nuxt.js

Nuxt.js has a static dir in which we add static files. If a file named img.jpg is located in this folder, it will be available by url: example.com/img.jpg.

Next, I have several Nuxt.js projects that use the same static files. Therefore, all of these resources use an external server: assets.example.com.

Now I need make request on example.com/img.jpg and receive file from my static server: example.com/img.jpg.

Tell me please, how it's possible use external server for static (publicPath does not work in this case)?

Comment: Why don't you reach for `assets.example.com/img.jpg` directly? If the image needs to be shared, rather than duplicating it everywhere, keep it in one place.

Comment: @kissu the task is to use the current domain for SEO

Comment: What's the relation between a remote resource (an image on top of it) and SEO? An image is not a semantic HTML structure. You can totally have some SEO with remote resources.

Comment: @kissu such a requirement. I can't do anything about it